# how to dynamically action an angular ng-include command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Is it possible to dynamically add an ng-include element to a HTML page and have it actioned?

I have a Drag N Drop application where you can drag an element onto the page and in the drop zone the element is replaced with a more detailed element. For examples you drag a box that says Calendar and when it is dropped a calendar is presented. To be clear a new Element is created and added to the DOM, it does not exist before the drop.

When the element is dropped, I'm hoping that I can replace it with a chunk of HTML that looks like below. Instead of having the markup defined in a string like it is at the moment which is not very nice:

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
    <h3 class='panel-title'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
      WIDGET NAME
      <spanclass='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class='widgetContainer' ng-include="'widgets/widget.html'"></div>
</div>
```

When the above HTML is inserted into the page the referenced HTML file is not included.

What I  would like to happen is a HTML file is loaded containing the widget markup and included at the appropriate position.

I'm new to Angular so I don't know if this is because:

- dynamically adding ng-include isn't supported
- whether I need to do something with the controller to handle this logic
- should I be using the tag instead of the attribute?
- it just isn't possible.

Please provide examples with solutions, as I said I'm new to Angular.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The code used to created the HTML that I want to dynamically add to the page looks like this

```
$("#template").append(
    " \
    <div class='panel panel-default'>\
    <div class='panel-heading'>\
    <h3 class='panel-title'>\
    <span style='padding-right: 10px; cursor:pointer;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='removeElement(this)'></span>\
    " + widgetDetail['serviceName'] + "\
    <span style='float:right; cursor:pointer;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog' onclick='toggleWidgetDetail(this)'></span>\
    </h3>\
    </div>\
    <div class='markupContainer' ng-include=\"'widgets/" + id +".html'\"></div>\
    </div>\
    "
);
```

I've uploaded the complete code to [GitHub](https://github.com/githublemming/cloudprovisioning). The drag and drop aspects are being handled currently by HTML5 javascript, which can be seen in the file `/public/javascripts/js_dragndrop.js`. The new widget being added to the page (the code above) is in `/public/javascripts/jq_dragndrop.js`

*I'm in the prototyping phase trying to work out the DragNDrop elements so don't expect high quality code :)*

Comment: This feels too broad to provide a solid answer.  You haven't shown the code that is handling the Drag & Drop aspect of the code; the markup that is presented doesn't have any "code" that would work or not work.  One might *assume* that you mean the markup isn't displayed, but that isn't clear in the question, and without the code that is inserting said markup, it's not possible to infer what your intent is or really where the problem might lie.

Comment: @Claies  Thanks for the comment. I've updated the question with more info and a link to the source on GitHub.

Comment: This looks like you are mixing JQuery with Angular, which complicates things slightly.  Angular won't update the ng-include here, since it was added without angular's knowledge.  If using pure angular isn't an option, then you would need some way to attach to angular and call scope.$apply()

Comment: @Claies I thought that might be the case. I'm not tied to JQuery for this task so I'll have a look around and see if I can find an AngularJS DragNDrop library that I can replace it with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of achieving what I wanted by moving the HTML5 drop and drop code into AngularJS directives and then (using this [ [Compile dynamic template from outside of angular](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/1fb8ae674df4c71f85cf) ] as a guide) got the html templates being loaded where I wanted them.

The main code change looks like this:

```
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {

  var widgetDetail = widgets[e.dataTransfer.getData('Text')];

  var obj = $("#template");
  var scope = obj.scope();

  obj.append(
    "<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'>\
     <span style='padding-right: 10px; cursor:pointer;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='removeWidget(this)'></span>\
     " + widgetDetail['serviceName'] + "\
     <span style='float:right; cursor:pointer;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog' onclick='toggleWidgetDetail(this)'></span>\
     </h3></div><div class='markupContainer' ng-include=\"'widgets/" + widgetDetail['serviceId'] + ".html'\"></div>\
     "
   );

   $compile(obj.contents())(scope);
   scope.$digest();
});
```

You can find the full code in the Git Project */public/controllers/template.js* if you are interested.